# How do you output 3 items on a single line in a file?

Tags: python, file-handling

I want to make a program that allows a user to keep entering sets of three items, one for each input prompt, and then output the three values to a single line in a text file.

Here is some basic example

```
text_file = open("filename", "w")

While True:
      Code = input("Enter code")
      Description = input("Enter description")
      Price = input("Enter price")
```

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
So this is where I am so far.

```
text_file = open("file.txt", "w")

while True:
      user_input = input("Enter a code, description and price")
      split = user_input.split(" ")
      split = str(split)
      text_file.write(split)
```

The only problem is it doesn't let me output a list.

Comment: Are you saying that the prompt should only be on one line, or that the user should be prompted three separate times, but have all that data written to a single line of the file?

Comment: @poisonishere: I think you still need to clarify "each three items".  Do you need help in having all three values *written* to one line of your output file -- or -- do you want to read all three values from a single input line before you write anything?  i think *I* got it correct, but the other people who answered obviously don't agree.

Comment: @Prune I want the three items on one line, but as he adds the next set of 3 items I want that to be on another line. Like this                                                  >>> A112 Mouse 25.55                                                                                                  >>> B112 Keyboard 50.00

Comment: Please clarify: one line of *input*, or one line of *output*?  That's the whole confusion.

Comment: @Prune Ah One line of output

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
sep = ','   # separator character
textfile.write(sep.join([Code, Description, Price]) + '\n')
```

Comment: I get an error saying that only one argument can be giving and that I'm giving three.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: OP said "How do you output 3 items on a single line in a file?"  Output, not input.  The file is open for writing.

Comment: @poisonishere: TheoretiCAL fixed my syntax; I forgot to wrap them in a list.

Comment: `textfile.write(sep.join([Code, Description, Price]) + '\n' )` - I think newline is necessary at the end.

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("filename.txt", "w") as f:
    while True: 
         f.write(input("Enter code : ")+' ')
         f.write(input("Enter description : ")+' ')
         f.write(input("Enter price : ")+'\n')
```

Comment: I do not think you want newline character after *every* print - just the last one.

Comment: If you're merely dumping the input to a file, this is a nice, tight, maintainable answer.  Note that it doesn't store the input values in the program: they're read, written, and lost.

Answer (score 3):

If using Python >= 3.6 and compatibility with older versions is not required:

```
text_file.write(f'{Code} {Description} {Price}\n')
```

Otherwise (adapted from another answer):

```
text_file.write('{} {} {}\n'.format(Code, Description, Price))
```

Note that it is the defacto standard convention that names of variables should start with a lowercase letter. So you should use `code`, `description`, and `price` for the variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the users splits the three fields with a space (i.e 1232 Example Product $24.95) you know that the first space separates the code from description, and the last space separates the description from price. Then:

```
text_file = open("filename", "w")

while True:
      user_input = input("Enter Code Description Price:")
      split_input = user_input.split(' ')
      code = split_input[0]
      description = ' '.join(split_input[1:-1])
      price = split_input[-1]

text_file.write('{} {} {}\n'.format(code, description, price))
```